# The recommended way to use the Delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

If the delegate is just a reference point to a method,then I think I should not use the delegate in the object-way (creating an instance of the delegate type).

This is the first snippet:

```
public delegate void Del1(string message);
public class Test
{
  public static void Method1(string message)
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
}
```

```
Test test new Test();
del1 handler=new del1(Test.Method1);
handler("Hello world!");
```

This is the second snippet:

```
public delegate void Del2(string message);
public static void Method2(string message)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

```
Del2 handler = Method2;
handler("Hello World");
```

The first way is more general for me.

The second way doesn't have to create an instance, is it just because the method it delegate is static?

If Yes, which one is more general in concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code snippets are identical.  The second is merely allowing the compiler to automatically infer the delegate type of the method group, instead of providing it explicitly.  You're creating an instance of a delegate in both cases.

Comment: thanks Servy, but when is the instance created  ? When I assign the address to it ?

Comment: @葛厚德 No, you have to create an instance before you can assign it to a variable.

Comment: ,so I will get two instances the delegate one,and the delegated one?But the Second snippet look like it doesn't need the instance of the delegate type.

Comment: @葛厚德 You'll create one instance of the delegate, and you'll assign a reference to that delegate to the variable.  If you think the second snippet doesn't create a delegate then you need to read the answer again.